# PostgreSQL replication locale issues (Ubuntu master, Windows slave)

Tags: windows, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

Master is Ubuntu 14.04, Slave is Windows 2008 R2 server, both running PostgreSQL 9.6.5 (64-bits). Am able to setup and start replication as per [this guide](https://www.openmakesoftware.com/postgresql-hot-standby-for-windows/). From psql I can confirm that changes are being replicated, but pgadmin4 will not let me connect due to the following error message:

`FATAL: database locale is incompatible with operating system DETAIL: The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "en_CA.UTF-8", which is not recognized by setlocale(). HINT: Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.`

It is my understanding that the locale is "en_CA.UTF-8" on Linux and "English_Canada.1252" on Windows and that they are somewhat not equivalent. Is this a pgadmin defect or did I forget to do something? I will try on Windows 2012 now.

Comment: streaming replication from linux to windows?. at least surprising. how did you copy initial set?

Comment: pg_basebackup as per guide linked

Comment: The best context I have found for this question is described here: https://superuser.com/a/1451686/1262875. The answer states why it's not possible, and that you might get away with more recent version of Windows. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68205029/9034699) however makes a compelling argument for why you should not even try. I have been following the rabbit hole the whole afternoon...

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo locale-gen en_CA.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: You should add explanation.