# Is it a problem to mix different OS versions in a PostgreSQL cluster?

Tags: postgresql

I have a cluster of PostgreSQL nodes using streaming replication and running on RHEL 7. I plan to add new nodes running on RHEL 8, still using the same PostgreSQL version (12.7). Is mixing OS versions in a cluster a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, streaming replication only works between the same OS and OS version.

While replicating between RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 might technically work, you might run into sever problems, e.g. because of different [locale data](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes) which can lead to incorrect query results on the standby server.

I would not risk this. You should keep all servers at the same OS versions and patch level.

Logical replication on the other hand can be used to replicate between different operating systems (e.g. even from Linux to Windows). But that will require more setup and isn't really suitable if you want to replicate many databases that contain many schemas.